# Set Nullable DataTime + MVC + ADO Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a problem that is a pain in the ass. See the next code:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.birth_date, new { @id = "datepicker")%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.birth_date)%>
```

When I submitting the form the value for birth_date is 01/01/0001 12:00:00 a.m. how do i stop this? I need a blank textbox.

I have this in my model:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Person_Validation))]
public partial class Person{
        }


public class Person_Validation{ 

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Needed Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please this format: dd/mm/yyyy")]

public DateTime? birth_date{
                    get;
                    set;
                }
    }
```

Some people said me that I only have to add a mark (?) or Nullable to Datatime, but I did this.

public DateTime? birth_date, and doesnt work for me. Please I need your help!!

Also I have to say that the main model Person was generated by ADO Entity Framework

Comment: If you want to use a Nullable DateTime, then you shouldn't define this `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Needed Date")]` in your model. I'm  just trying to help, but I can't understand if you want a required datetime or not....

Comment: "submitting the form" sounds like the problem occurs when the form is submitted back to the server, but "I need a blank textbox" sounds like the problem occurs when the view is displayed for the first time.  Which is it?

Comment: Yes Daniel, the problem occurs when the view is displayed at first time, I need blank textbox when the view is displayed for the first time, will be filled later with jquery Datapicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three possibilities:

1. Change the date field in the database to nullable and then regen you EDMX.
2. I'm assuming your are using Sql Server, you can change the datefield from datetime to datetime2.
3. You can catch the birthdate in the UI before it's rendered to the user and check for DateTime.MinValue

   if(model.birth_date == DateTime.MinValue)
   {
      ... make magic.
   }

Comment: Thank you soo much!!! Chuck I use the first answer. 1) Change the date field in the database to nullable and then regen you EDMX.